# Setting Vagrant Scotch-Box IP to 127.0.0.1

Tags: php

I just stopped use XAMPP and switch to Vagrant Scotch-Box on my PHP website project.

The way my website using to detect whether is from local server by using this:

```
$_SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1' || $_SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '::1'
```

It worked very well in XAMPP, because XAMPP website always on 127.0.0.1

Now I need to change Vagrant Scotch-Box ip to 127.0.0.1 (default is 192.168.33.10)

Here is in my Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "127.0.0.1"
```

Here is in my host file

```
127.0.0.1 mywebsite
```

I `vagrant provision` after adjust these value.

Any ideas?thanks!